# Jquery Calculating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I running a similar script to this script from fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/2/

I tried to modify it to work with my table.

Here is the link to the table on the product page

http://styleso1.nextmp.net/dev/shop/safari-pu-sleeve-jacket.html

I need it to calculate the Qty ( input box, Column 4) X the unit price ( Column 5 ) and show the sum in column 6

How would i modify the JS to do this?

Here is what i have for the JS

```
$(function(){
function ca(){
    var $overall = 0;

    $("tr.sum").each(function() {

        var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
        var $price = $(this).find("td").eq(1);

        console.log($qnt + " | " + $price);

        var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat($qnt.val());

        $(this).find(".a-center1").text(sum);

        $overall += sum;

    });

    $("#total").text($overall);
}

$(function() {

    ca();
    $('input.qty').bind('change keyup',function(){ca();});

});
```

Any Help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  $("tr.sum").each(function() {

        var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
        var $price = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").find('.price');

        console.log($qnt + " | " + $price);
        var pri = $price.text();
            pri = pri.replace('$', '');
        var sum = parseFloat(pri) * parseFloat($qnt.val());

        $(this).find("td").eq(5).text('$' + sum);

        $overall += sum;

    });
    $("#total").text('$' +$overall);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Jk976/2/)**

Comment: looks like there is a $ in the price field.. Check edited post

Comment: Did not change, It is taking column 2 ( instead of column 6 ) and multiplying it by qty and putting sum in column 3 ( instead of column 6 )

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that it can be easier yo understand

Comment: It looks like i almost have it.
http://jsfiddle.net/b9FY7/8/

How do I remove the $ from the $price. and put it back in after i calculates. So it shows in column 6 under "Price" and in "Total"

Comment: How would i add the $ back in after it calculates? in both column 6 and for total?

Comment: I have updated that in the fiddle ... Just do this $("#total").text('$' +$overall);

Comment: How do i remove all non numeric from the input qty this fiddle
I know ".replace(/\D/g,"");" would work. but where would i add it here
They are give me NAN errors
http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8aC/

Comment: Add this in your code tupp = isNaN(tupp) ? 0 : tupp;
        qnt= isNaN(qnt) ? 0 : qnt;
        sum= isNaN(sum) ? 0 : sum; .. Check http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Lw8aC/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can save some DOM searching and text parsing by doing some simple things like adding the unit price as a data attribute to the row and retrieving it with jQuery `data()` method

HTML

```
<tr class="sum" data-unit_price="10.00">
```

JS

```
function ca(){
    var $overall = 0;

    $("tr.sum").each(function() {
         var $row=$(this);
        var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
        var cost = $row.data('unit_price');       

        var sum = cost * parseFloat($qnt.val());

        $(this).find("td").eq(5).text('$' +sum);

        $overall += sum;

    });

    $("#total").text('$' +$overall);
}

$(function() {

    ca();
    $('input.qty').bind('change keyup', ca);

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Jk976/3/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added that. Much better then me hiding the column.

How do i fix "$NaN" if the user deletes the value?

Comment: How do i remove all non numeric from the input qty this fiddle
I know ".replace(/\D/g,"");" would work. but where would i add it here
They are give me NAN errors
http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8aC/